# Run changeSet based on non-executed file

Tags: xml, oracle, liquibase

We have a changelog file (xml) in our repo for XSD's. This file contains changeSets with an sqlFile changeType pointing to a script.sql for each XSD we have.
The script to register the XSD on the DB doesnt change.
The XSD file (also in the repo) *does* change.

Currently, when the XSD file changes, we add an extra changeSet that points to the same script.sql, which in turn executes file.xsd (which has changed contents, but an unchanged name).

I am trying to find a way to make the changeSet run on change, but not on the change of script.sql, but of file.xsd.

I scoured most of the liquibase docs and couldn't find a changeType or attribute that could help me. I was hoping to find a changeType which would reference a file, but not execute it, and then include it in the same changeSet

```
<changeSet id="some-id" author="me" runOnChange="true">
  <sqlFile splitStatements="false" path="path/to/file/script.sql" />
  <checkThisFile path="path/to/file/file.xsd" />
</changeSet>
```

I also checked the preconditions tag, but (except from writing a custom precondition) i was unsuccesful there as well.

Is it possible to achieve this behaviour?